# pyspark -> symbol name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the `->` symbol for pyspark used here called? If I want to query google for queries that uses this how to do it? I want to know how to do 'OR' condition using this. I thought this is lambda but then we have a `lambda` keyword, this is not '`map`' either.

```
spark.sql.functions.expr('filter((calls, x -> substring(x.call, 0, 23)))')
```

Comment: Can you specify which `filter` method you're using here? Maybe you're calling on some class? Also it seems like your parentheses aren't closed here, is the function signature longer than what you've typed here?

Comment: yes it is not closed. I have edited. EXPR spark sql

Answer (score 1):

This does indeed the same thing as a lambda expression. In terms of Python, the `'filter((calls, x -> substring(x.call, 0, 23)))'` part is just a string. What happens inside of that string is not Python anymore (hence no need to use the `lambda` keyword).

##### Some extra info that might demistify what happens here a bit

The `spark.sql.functions.expr` function expects a SQL like string as its input. Spark uses [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) to parse those SQL-like strings into query plans. This ANTLR parser uses `.g4` files to define the grammar of what you want to parse. In these files in the source code, we can confirm what I said above here (using Spark v3.4.1 here):

In [`SqlBaseLexer.g4`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBaseLexer.g4#L415) the `->` sign gets called `ARROW`:

```
ARROW: '->';
```

In [`SqlBarseParser.g4`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBaseParser.g4#L913-L914) these `ARROW` expressions get the label `lambda`:

```
    | identifier ARROW expression                                                              #lambda
    | LEFT_PAREN identifier (COMMA identifier)+ RIGHT_PAREN ARROW expression                   #lambda
```

Without really going deep down into how ANTLR works, you see that this `ARROW` gets the label `lambda`, hinting towards the fact that this gets parsed as a lambda expression but just has a different syntax.